# Python - replace all words in a string except some

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

Given a text like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac massa arcu.
```

I want to write a function that replaces all the words in a text, except some defined in a list **keep_list**, with a given string **xxxx**. So, if

```
keep_list = ['amet', 'ac']
```

I'd like to have an output like

```
xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx amet, xxxx xxxx xxxx. xxxx ac xxxx xxxx.
```

I want to keep all commas, points etc. of the original string and this is the only difficulty of this function.

How would you do it in an elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to use a regular expression to match single words, and then pass a callback to `re.sub()` to replace with `xxxx` if the word is not in the list.

```
import re

txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac massa arcu.'
keep = ['amet', 'ac']

print(re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda w: w.group() if w.group() in keep else 'xxxx', txt))
```

Comment: the kind of elegant solution I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: Very nice! And easily extendable if someone e.g. would like to have the hidden words the same length like in the original text `re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda w: w.group() if w.group() in keep else len(w.group())*'x', txt)` or that the x's should even reflect the uppercase letters `re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda w: w.group() if w.group() in keep else ''.join(['x', 'X'][c.isupper()] for c in w.group()), txt)`